# How to set a custom SFTP port with phpseclib

Tags: php, sftp, phpseclib

I have to connect to SFTP server by using PHP. I am using phpseclib for that. I found some example on Internet, but I am not able to connect to SFTP. I am using a custom port (2222) to connect to SFTP. Please tell me where I can define custom port to connect to SFTP.

```
<?php
include('Net/SFTP.php');

$sftp = new Net_SFTP('www.domain.tld');
if (!$sftp->login('username', 'password')) {
    exit('Login Failed');
}
?>
```

It is showing "Login Failed".

Comment: Give us more information. See http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/documentation/net.html#net_ssh_debug

Comment: I am running the same code. when i connecting using filezilla i have to specify port 2222. But when i trying connecting using phpseclib by using code "Net_SFTP('www.domain.tld', 2222);" I am not able to connect. I changed the port in SFTP.php also. But still getting "Login Failed".

Comment: The link shows how to enable logging and retrieve the log. Please do that and include the log into your question.

Comment: it show Array() Login Failed

Comment: Please include your new complete code, including the debug statements.

Comment: <?php
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . './phpseclib');
include('Net/SFTP.php');
define('NET_SFTP_LOGGING', NET_SFTP_LOG_COMPLEX);
$sftp = new Net_SFTP('IP Address',2222);
if (!$sftp->login('username', 'password')) {

exit('Login Failed');
}
else{
echo "connected";
}
echo $sftp->pwd() . "\r\n";

print_r($sftp->nlist());
print_r($sftp->getSFTPErrors());
echo $sftp->getLog();

?>

Comment: Well, we need to see the log, when it fails. So can you move the `echo $sftp->getLog();` and `print_r($sftp->getSFTPErrors())` just before `exit('Login Failed');` ? I also do not understand where you got that "Array()" from, as you have no debugging code before the `exit`. Anyway, next time, please edit your question to include more information (see "edit" link below the question). So not post multi-line code/output to comments, it's unreadable.

Comment: Apologize for last. I moved these two lines  before "Login Failed". I am getting Array () Login Failed.

Comment: Why did you posted [the same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28236469/phpseclib-showing-login-failed) again?

Comment: Do `define('NET_SSH2_LOGGING', NET_SSH2_LOG_COMPLEX)` - not `define('NET_SFTP_LOGGING', NET_SFTP_LOG_COMPLEX)`. The latter only captures SFTP layer packets and SSH2 operates at a layer below SFTP. So to diagnose SSH2 issues it's SSH2 logs that we'd need to see. Also, `$sftp->getLog()` returns SSH2 logs. If you wanted SFTP logs you'd need to use `$sftp->getSFTPLog()`.

Answer (score 16):

You can define a custom port like so:

```
Net_SFTP('www.domain.tld', 2222);
```

You can see it when you look in the constructor from `SFTP` class which is like this:

```
function Net_SFTP($host, $port = 22, $timeout = 10)
{

}
```

Comment: It is showing login failed....Actually I am using Ip address instead of www.domain.tld.

Comment: I can't help you further. You have to give more information.