# Phpseclib showing Login Failed

Tags: php, ftp, sftp, phpseclib

I am connecting SFTP server by using the phpseclib. I am using custom port to connect to SFTP. It is connected successfully using filezilla with port number 2222. When i connected using phpseclib it showing Login failed. I am using the code:

```
<?php
   set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . './phpseclib');
   include('Net/SFTP.php');
   define('NET_SFTP_LOGGING', NET_SFTP_LOG_COMPLEX);
    $sftp = new Net_SFTP('IP Address',2222); 
   if (!$sftp->login('username', 'password')) {
 print_r($sftp->getSFTPErrors()); 
   echo $sftp->getLog();
        exit('Login Failed');
    }
     else{ echo "connected";
     } 
    echo $sftp->pwd() . "\r\n"; 
    print_r($sftp->nlist());
    ?>
```

Please help

Comment: Do `define('NET_SSH2_LOGGING', NET_SSH2_LOG_COMPLEX)` - not SFTP logging. And post the log too. If you feel it's too large then you can post it to pastebin.com and post the link. That said phpseclib does fsockopen to open up the network connection and there are circumstances where fsockopen won't even work. eg. http://stackoverflow.com/q/22890840/569976#comment34945963_22890840

Comment: Why did you post [the same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28231888/how-to-set-a-custom-sftp-port-with-phpseclib) again?

Comment: I am getting this log...http://pastebin.com/cVFVeCYn

Comment: That log has no formatting what-so-ever. That alone makes me think you're running an out-of-date version as the latest version detects the php sapi and adds <pre> tags depending on that. I can try to parse through your logs but I'll have to write a custom script to do so. Maybe I'll do that this weekend. You could make this whole thing move along a lot faster if you reobtained the logs and put them in <pre> tags.